# How to toggle this element?

Tags: javascript, function, object, d3.js, toggle

i am using d3 to toggle a function. I want to make an visible object hide when i click and when you click again, it will be visible again.

Now i got this function:

```
 .on("click", function(d) {         object1.style("visibility", "hidden");}
        )
```

Currently, i only can click it and the object will hide, but i cannot toggle.
I found this nice example, that can make it happen: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5d621a60e2d1d02086bf

In this example the code to toggle looks like this:

```
         .on("click", function(){       // Determine if current line is visible
                var active   = blueLine.active ? false : true,
                  newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;      
  // Hide or show the elements      
    d3.select("#blueLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
    d3.select("#blueAxis").style("opacity", newOpacity);        
      // Update
         whether or not the elements are active         
      blueLine.active = active;     })
      .text("Blue Line");
```

I got a question about the code. You define a new variable

```
var active   = blueLine.active ? false : true
```

and you check, if the current status is active, for example if yes, then
`var active = false`  ?

That means for the next line:

```
newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1
```

is similiar in this example to `newOpacity = false ? 0 : 1` means `newOpacity =  1` ? Is that correct? And then, at this line:

```
blueLine.active = active
```

turns to `blueLine.active = false` ? Hope someone could help me out of this confusion, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you linked, the variable (or property) the code toggles at each click is `blueLine.active`. This line:

```
var active   = blueLine.active ? false : true
```

means: "if `blueLine.active` is true, `active` is false; if `blueLine.active` is false, `active` is true".

And then, at the end of the function, comes the line that actually toggles `blueLine.active`:

```
blueLine.active = active;
```

What it does is: if `blueLine.active` was false when the user clicked the text, `blueLine.active` is now true; if `blueLine.active` was true when the user clicked the text, `blueLine.active` is now false. It toggles between true and false (pay attention to this: the first time you click the text, `blueLine.active` is actually undefined).

Then, you set the opacity according to `blueLine.active` or `active`, it doesn't matter.

You can get the same effect with a single boolean:

```js
var circle = d3.select("circle")
var toggle = true;
d3.select("text").on("click", ()=>{
 circle.style("visibility", toggle ? "hidden" : "visible");
 toggle = !toggle;
})
```

```css
text {
 cursor: pointer;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="20" fill="teal"></circle>
 <text x="20" y="100">Click me</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks again, Gerardo! Can you maybe give me a short explanation, what this means? `()=>`

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions